# Await a function that has a for loop syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, discord.py

I am trying to get a discord bot to be able to upload all images from a folder when a user types 'uploadAll'. The code is:

```
def get_image(path):
    image_list = []
    for filename in glob.glob(path): #appends opened images from folder
        im = Image.open(filename)    #into list image_list and returns it
        image_list.append(im)
    return image_list

async def iter_image(path):          #uploads images in the list
    for i in get_image(path):
        client.send_file(discord.Object(id='SERVER_ID'),i)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def uploadAll(self):           #Should trigger above method
    await iter_image('PATH_TO_FOLDER')
```

The last function results in:
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression. I can't await iter_image because it has a for-loop. Any solutions on how I can get an event-loop to trigger the for-loop? Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't send to a server ID or discord.Server object any more. That worked when the default channel shared its ID with the server, but servers are no longer guarenteed to have a channel with this property as the concept of "default channel" was removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it should work if you add `await` here

```
await client.send_file(discord.Object(id='SERVER_ID'), i)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but I get another error:
Task exception was never retrieved

Comment: Hey I don't know if you ever got it fixed, but I believe you could try putting the line in a try/except